# Servicestack mini profiler

Tags: servicestack, mvc-mini-profiler

I have a separate servicestack project acting as my api where i would like to implement the profiler, but i'm a bit confused on how to view the profiler data.

My website which is in another project sends request to the api, which means i am not preseneted with the profiler data.

I've followed these instructions https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Built-in-profiling, but how do i simulate a call from a website to the api, so i can see the profiler data?

Should i just log the profiler data in the database instead?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the profiler is only visible when viewing the ServiceStack generated pages for your services. It's in the top right. I'm not sure how else you could view the profiler data. To profile your website that calls ServiceStack services, you'd have to install mini profiler there, but that profiler would only be profiling the website.

[image]

Comment: Fair enough. So how would i see a profiling on a post request? I don't recall an input field where you can submit the post data.

Comment: @AllanVraa if you make subsequent calls to your service from the outside they still get computed and if you refresh the ServiceStack auto generated pages you'll see them listed. You probably figured that out, I'm just posting here for future reference.